# Create drawable resource path dynamically

Tags: android

I have something like the following line of code:

```
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_XX, "Notify", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

My problem is that i want to make `R.drawable.notification_XX` changeable, so for example if I have a variable `i = 24;` then the appropriate resource `R.drawable.notification_24` should be used

So, is there a way of creating a drawable resource path dynamically?

thanks in advance, Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the Notification to display a number you can just set [the `number` field of your `Notification` object](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number) and the appropriate number will be overlaid over your icon in the Notifications bar.

However, if you really have a number of different icons you can use the [`getIdentifier()` method on `Resources`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which will return the Resource ID for a given name.

Comment: the getIdentifier() way works perfectly in my case - thanks a lot!